# My windows phone 8 app UI stops responding after using the mediaplayer class to play a song from my phone library, How can I fix this?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My code snippet below:

```
using (library = new MediaLibrary())
{
     MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs, 0);
}
```

and then my app user Interface is no longer responsive after playing the song. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I used a dispatcher timer class like this:

```
private DispatcherTimer m_dispatcherTimer;

public MainPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        m_dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        m_dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(10000);
        m_dispatcherTimer.Tick += frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick;
        m_dispatcherTimer.Start();
        using (library = new MediaLibrary())
        {
          MediaPlayer.Play(library.Songs, 0);
        }

}

void frameworkDispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
}
```

and everything worked just fine. ;)